# Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Getting this exception on the below code.

**Code:**

```
when(INV['VFA_EXTRA_AM'].isNull(), None)
                    .otherwise((INV['VFA_EXTRA_AM'].cast(DecimalType(12,2))/INV['EXTRAADULT_COUNT_CHECK']
                                ).cast(DecimalType(12,2))).alias("PER_PRSN_VFA_EXTRA_AM"),
                    when(INV['VFC_EXTRA_AM'].isNull(), None)
                    .otherwise((INV['VFC_EXTRA_AM'].cast(DecimalType(12, 2))/INV['EXTRACHILD_COUNT_CHECK']
                                ).cast(DecimalType(12, 2))).alias("PER_PRSN_VFC_EXTRA_AM"),
                    when(INV['VFI_EXTRA_AM'].isNull(), None)
                    .otherwise((INV['VFI_EXTRA_AM'].cast(DecimalType(12, 2))/INV['EXTRAINFANT_COUNT_CHECK']
                                ).cast(DecimalType(12, 2))).alias("PER_PRSN_VFI_EXTRA_AM"))
```

`INV` is the DataFrame name.

**Error log:**

```
  File "/mnt/dclrms-cogs/resbaseline/Integration.py", line 52, in execueIntegration
    ).cast(DecimalType(12, 2))).alias("PER_PRSN_VFI_EXTRA_AM"))\
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1040, in select
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 895, in _jcols
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 882, in _jseq
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 60, in _to_seq
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 48, in _to_java_column
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 41, in _create_column_from_name
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: can't find usage of `col` method in code you've published.

Comment: @Volodymyr Glushak: I'm using DataFrame variable name instead of Col function.

Comment: exception should be different then! Publish whole stack trace.

Comment: @VolodymyrGlushak: Please check now, i have done same kind of checks many place, and it was workig, here i'm missing something.

Comment: You did not provide full sample. The snippet you've published can't have such issue. If you can share reproducable sample I'll be able to help.